# no logro enlace con tabla de db

Tags: mysqli, php7

la conexión al servidor y db se realiza correctamente, pero no logro desplegar los registros de la tabla puesto que no logro enlazar con la misma,estoy luchando con la sintaxis en códigos y no es eso,es el enlace con la tabla de registros.

```
<?php
include("conexion.php")
?>
<DOCTYPE html>       
    <body>
        <header>
        <h1>BASE DE DATOS EMPLEADOS</h1>
        </header>
       
            <?php
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
            $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);            
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            ?>           
            <tr>
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['id'] ?></td>
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['nombre'] ?></td>
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['apellido'] ?></td>     
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['sexo'] ?></td>
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['cargo'] ?></td>
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['depto'] ?></td>  
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['edad'] ?></td>
            <td class="tituloss"><?php echo $row['telefono'] ?></td> 
           
        </tr>
            <?php
                }
               
            ?>              
        </table>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Los `<?php echo blah >?` se pueden reemplazar por `<?= blah ?>`

Comment: @eftshift0 siempre y cuando esa sintaxis este habilitada de lo contrario no va a funcionar

Comment: @BetaM detalles, detalles :-D

Comment: _Detalles detalles_ que el 90% de las preguntas terminan encontrando que son la causa de todo. No es sano confundir a otros que posiblemente no sepan de dónde salen esos detalles. Seamos cuidadosos

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias cosas en tu código:

1. Cuando trabajas con `table` debes abrir adecuadamente la etiqueta `<table>`, de lo contrario la tabla no se mostrará.
2. No deberías lanzar la creación de la tabla hasta no estar seguro de que en la consulta hay datos. Muchas cosas pueden fallar y necesitarás controlar esos fallos.
3. Para no hacerte tanto lío con el código evita mezclas constantes de bloques PHP/HTML. En estos casos yo suelo usar un sólo bloque con todo el código PHP y concatenar las cosas en variables.

Intenta esto:

```
<DOCTYPE html>       
    <body>
        <header>
        <h1>BASE DE DATOS EMPLEADOS</h1>
        </header>
<?php
    include("conexion.php");
    if ($conn) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        if($result && $result->num_rows > 0){
            $html="<table>";
            $td="<td class=\"tituloss\">%s</td>";          
            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $html.="<tr>";
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['id']);
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['nombre']);
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['apellido']);
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['sexo']);
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['cargo']);
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['depto']);
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['edad']);
                    $html.=sprintf($td,$row['telefono']);
                $html.="</tr>";
            }
            $html.="</table>";
        } else {
            $html="No se encontraron filas o hubo error en la consulta. Verifique...";
        }
    }else{
        $html="No hay conexión. Revise el nombre de la variable o las credenciales";
    }
    echo $html;
?>          
    </body>
</html>
```

El código queda más claro y organizado así y puedes revisar cualquier error.

Comment: Pue si menciona que no se encontraron filas o hubo un error en la consulta..

Comment: @Erik debes verificar entonces que la conexión es correcta y que esa tabla existe y tiene datos. ¿`conexion.php` está en la misma carpeta del actual script? ¿verificaste que conecta bien a la base de datos?

Comment: Lo curioso es que tengo instalado xampp y localmente realiza excelente las consultas pero, en mi hosting no lo hace, en los dos lugares utilizo phpMyAdmin..alguna idea?

Comment: @Erik he agregado otro nivel de verificación en el código que controla el estado de la conexión. Implementa el código así y si arroja el mensaje de `No hay conexión. Revise el nombre de la variable o las credenciales` entonces queda claro que algo está fallando en tu forma de conectarte y deberías revisar a ese nivel. Espero tu comentario al respecto una vez hayas probado.

Comment: Ejecuto y comento

Comment: sigue enviando el mismo error Connected successfully No se encontraron filas o hubo error en la consulta. Verifique...

Comment: De hecho envié un correo a mi proveedor de Hosting,preguntando si existe alguna restricción en cuanto al manejo de la db,estoy en espera de la respuesta..

Comment: @Erik OK, eso confirma que no es un problema de la conexión. Ahora, revisa en `conexion.php` **a qué base de datos te estás conectando**. Abre esa BD en phpMyAdmin (**del hosting**) y verifica si tiene una tabla `clientes` y si esa tabla tiene datos.

Comment: Si tiene datos yo soy quien la elaboro e inserto los datos, phpMyAdmin local tengo Maria DB 10.4.13 y en el hosting MYSQL 5.7.31, podría haber conflicto

Comment: He vuelto a realizar todo desde cero en la db remota y parece que ya jalo